# Движение одного RectTransform к другому(вычисление правильных координат)

Tags: unity3d

Есть один RectTransform(кнопка) он потомок n колена канваса, также у нее смещенный пайвот(0,0) она находится в нижнем левом углу экрана, есть другой RectTransform(картинка) он также потомок nго колена канваса, но он находится в popup, который на одном уровне иерархии с кнопкой. Суть в чем нужно переместить эту картинку к кнопке. С перемещением(через лерп и корутину) проблем нет, но проблема в том, что у картинки anchoredPosition другой чем у кнопки, если я вручную двигаю ее к кнопке через эдитор, то ее anchoredPosition кардинально отличается от anchoredPosition кнопки. Собственно как мне вычислить для них координаты, что бы я мог передвинуть эту картинку к кнопке.
Пример лерпа

```
//Двигать двигает но не к кнопке, так как разные anchoredPosition
private IEnumerator MoveItemsToCollectionsButtonAnim()
    {
        int reachedItems = 0;
        float maxRange = 0.3f * 0.3f;
        Vector3 target = this.collectionButton.anchoredPosition;
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var item in this.itemsTransforms)
            {
                item.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(item.anchoredPosition, target, Time.deltaTime * this.moveItemsSpeed);
                Vector2 difPos = target - item.anchoredPosition;
                if (difPos.sqrMagnitude < maxRange)
                {
                    reachedItems++;
                }
            }

            if (reachedItems == this.items.Count)
            {
                yield return ScaleCollectionButtonAnim();
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector3 TargetPos = WorldToUISpace(YourCanvas, CollectionsButton.transform.position);
TargetPos += YourItemGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.center; // PivotPoint*TextureSize
YourItemGameObject.AddComponent<MoveItemsTo>().StartMove(TargetPos, 1f);
```

*Функцию `WorldToUISpace` смотрите в ответе Влада Леонидова.

---

```
public class MoveItemsTo : MonoBehaviour {
    float MoveTimer, MoveTime;
    bool Move;
    Vector3 MoveFrom, MoveTo;

    public void StartMove (Vector3 target, float moveTime) {
        MoveFrom = transform.position;
        MoveTo = target;
        MoveTime = moveTime;
        MoveTimer = 0;
        Move = true;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Move) {
            MoveTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            float Way = MoveTimer/MoveTime;
            if (Way < 1) {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(MoveFrom, MoveTo, Way);
            } else {
                transform.position = MoveTo;
                Move = false;
                Destroy(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Ярослава в общем правильный, но так как я работаю с элементами канваса, то worldPosition(transform.position) нужно преобразовать с мировых координат в координаты канваса, собственно в этом и был вопрос.
Как-то так:

```
public static Vector3 WorldToUISpace(Canvas parentCanvas, Vector3 worldPos)
    {
        Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPos);
        Vector2 result;

        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, screenPos, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out result);
        return parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(result);
    }
```

и присваивать `transform.position = WorldToUISpace(сanvas, worldPos);`

Comment: Уповал на то, что у него Scree Space - Overlay или камера стоит на месте =)